# on_message_edit looping on itself discord.py rewrite v1.3.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

This is my code -

````
@client.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    channel = client.get_channel(724859369732177953)
    guild = client.get_guild(716816535309516840)
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{guild.name}", description=f"**{before.author.mention} edited a message in - {before.channel.mention}**\n**Old -**\n ```\n {before.content}\n```\n**New -**\n```\n{after.content}\n```", color=0x40cc88,)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=guild.icon_url)
    embed.set_footer(text=guild.name)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    return
````

When I edit a message, the first embed that the bot send s is correct, but it keeps on sending the embeds again and again untit I exit the process, here is the screenshot-

[image: screenshot]

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the very beginning of your event check if it's triggered by the bot. You can do something like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    if before.author == client.user:
        return
    channel = client.get_channel(724859369732177953)
    ...
```

That will return if the bot edited a message. Otherwise it will execute the code as anticipated.